# Cypher query to find users who are connected to at least two other user in given list

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm an ultimate neo4j beginner. I have a cypher query similar to

```
WITH ["123", "456", "789"] as ids
MATCH (p:user)-[:follower]->(m:user)
WHERE m.id in ids
WITH p, 2 as inputCnt, count(DISTINCT p) as cnt
WHERE cnt = inputCnt
RETURN p
```

123, 456 and 789 are user ids. List length is dynamic, can be larger than 3.

What I'm trying to find is 123, 456, 789, plus other nodes which are following at least 2 users in given list. If a node is following only 1 user, it's not needed.

I got the main idea from [here](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/performing-match-intersection/) but apparently the problem there is different so my query doesn't return any results. I'm sure there's exactly 1 node in my graph which satisfies my condition, so I should see a result with 4 nodes.

Let me give some examples to clarify:

> When there are no users following at least 2 of them return:

[image: nn]

When there are no users following at least 2 of them, but they are following among themselves, return:

[image]

> When there's a single user, say (000), following 123 and 456 return:

[image]

> When there are two users, say 000 and XXX, one following all 3 of
> them, one following 2 of them, return:

[image]

Comment: You should count distinct m users rather than p.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "at least 2 users" then it should be >= rather than =.  Then you count distinct users m that are followed by another users p1, p2,..,pn.

```
WITH ["123", "456", "789"] as ids
MATCH (p:user)-[:follower]->(m:user)
WHERE m.id in ids
WITH p, count(DISTINCT m) as cnt where cnt >= 2
RETURN p
```

If you want to return users m then do a collect and check the size.

```
WITH ["123", "456", "789"] as ids
MATCH (p:user)-[:follower]->(m:user)
WHERE m.id in ids
WITH p, collect(DISTINCT m) as m_users where size(m_users) >= 2
RETURN p, m_users
```

EDIT:

> 1. Do a match of users from the id list
> 2. Using OPTIONAL match, find all followers to m
> 3. Check if the count is >= 2 OR no connection to the list OR connection within the list
> 4. Return distinct followers p and users m

```
WITH [ "222" , "333", "789"] as ids
MATCH (m:user) WHERE m.ID in ids
WITH collect(m) as ms
OPTIONAL MATCH (p:user)-[:follower]->(m) WHERE m in ms  
WITH p, ms, collect(DISTINCT m) as m_users  
  WHERE size(m_users) >= 2 OR p is null OR p in ms
WITH p,  ms + m_users as allUsers
UNWIND allUsers as m
RETURN distinct p, m
```

See below result:
[image]

Comment: How can I return given nodes in addition to the p? When I do "return p,m" it says m is undefined, when I add m like "WITH m,p,count(...." I get empty resultset

Comment: m users are already in the list as ids in line 1. Do you mean you want to know which m users are followed by users p?

Comment: even if there wasn't a "p" which satisfies the query, I want to return nodes given in ids list. If there is a single p, it should return ids + p and p's relations to the ids

Comment: please give us a good examples. It is getting complicated now. You can edit the question above and show us the expected results when 1) there is only one follower or 2) no follower and 3) two followers.

Comment: I tried to explain it more clearly, I hope it's ok.